# How can I connect my Login jsp application with LDAP?

Tags: java, jsp, ldap, ldap-query, ldapconnection

For authenticating I have used mysql database.
But now my task is to authenticate using LDAP server.
I install LDAP-Apache Directory Studio, but I don`t exactly know how I could connect with my application in Eclipse.
I want to authenticate and receive some information for user that is logged.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorial out there about how you connect to LDAP from java. Package  `javax.naming.`

Comment: Please show me a good example.